# iterate through a set goes to infinite loop

Tags: c++11, for-loop, iterator, each

i used exactly the same code in both of my files.
and one is work properly while the other one (this one) goes to endless loop.

```
int arr[5] = {3, 1, 3, 5, 6};
int main() {
    int T = 1; 
    set<int> s;
    for (int tc = 0; tc < T; tc++) {
        s.emplace(0);
        for (auto x : arr) {
            auto end = s.end();
            for (auto it = s.begin(); it != end; it++) {
                // here's where goes to infinite loop
                // and i couldn't figure out why..
                s.emplace(*it+x); 
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

below one is well working one

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {3,1,3,5,6}, sum=20;
    set<int> s;
    s.emplace(sum);
    for (auto x : arr) {
        auto end = s.end();
        for (auto it = s.begin(); it != end; it++) {
            s.emplace(*it-x);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

expected results are s = {1, 4, 7, 8, ...}
all the sum of all the subset of arr.
but not working properly.. i don't know why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're inserting elements into the set while iterating over it (with the ranged-for loop). The ranged-for loop semantics do not involve remembering the state of the range before the loop started; it's just like writing:

```
for(auto it = std::begin(container); it < std::end(container); it++)
```

Now, `std::set` is an *ordered* container. So when you insert/emplace elements *smaller* than the one your iterator points at, you won't see them later on in the iteration; but if you insert *larger* elements, you *will* see them. So you end up iterating only over elements you've inserted, infinitely.

What you should probably be doing is *not* emplace new elements into `s` during the iteration, but rather place them in some other container, then finally dump all of that new containers' contents into the set (e.g. with an `std::inserter` to the set and an `std::copy`).

(Also, in general, all of your code seems kind of suspect, i.e. I doubt you really want to do any of this stuff in the first place.)

Comment: could you tell me what's the more good way to get the same result..?

Comment: @flanElf: If you appreciate it, then accept it please. As for a "better way" - I'm not sure I would even try to achieve the same result. I don't know what you're doing any why, but I have a hunch you're going about it the wrong way. Consider asking a different question describing the problem you're trying to solve and your approach to the solution.